# How to update a Numpy array sequentially without loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sequence

I have a Numpy array **v** and I want to update each element using a function on the current element of the array :

```
v[i] = f(v, i)
```

A basic way to do this is to use a loop

```
for i in xrange(2, len(v)):
    v[i] = f(v, i)
```

Hence the value used to update **v[i]** is the updated array **v**. Is there a way to do these updates without a loop ?

For example,

```
v = [f(v, i) for i in xrange(len(v))]
```

does not work since the **v[i-1]** is not updated when it is used in the comprehensive list.

IThe function **f** can depend on several elements on the list, those with index lower than i should be updated and those with an index greater than i are not yet updated, as in the following example :

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f = lambda v, i: (v[i-1] + v[i]) / v[i+1]  # for i = [1,3]
f = lambda v, i: v[i]                      # for i = {0,4}
```

it should return

```
v = [1, (1+2)/3, (1+4)/4, ((5/4)+4)/5, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for this:

```
import numpy

v = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

numpy.add.accumulate(v)
#>>> array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15])
```

This works on many different types of `ufunc`:

```
numpy.multiply.accumulate(v)
#>>> array([  1,   2,   6,  24, 120])
```

For an arbitrary function doing this kind of accumulation, you can make your own `ufunc`, although this will be much slower:

```
myfunc = numpy.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: x + y, 2, 1)
myfunc.accumulate([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
#>>> array([1, 3, 6], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This method works well if the v at the index i is updated using only the index i-1. But it does not work with a function like f(v[i]) = v[i-1] + v[i] + v[i+1], since accumulate needs only function with two arguments.

Comment: I edited my question to add the case where f has three arguments.

Comment: @haron You should probably ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sum` function for sum the numbers before `v[i]`:

```
>>> v = [v[i] + sum(v[:i]) for i in xrange(len(v))]
>>> v
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

or in a better way you can use [np.cumsum()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)

```
>>> np.cumsum(v)
array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15])
```

Comment: Considering Numpy's use in large arrays, O(n²) algorithms are actually going to be worse than a pure-python loop, and this isn't even vectorized.